# why is my Second foreach loop not working after the first in php file?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

The following code is supposed to take incoming todo task from a database and divide them into their state of being done, such as todo, working, and finished, but for some reason after my first foreach loop which fires just fine, the other foreach loops don't seem to do anything?

```
<?php  
        require_once 'app/init.php';
        $itemQuery = $db->prepare("SELECT id, name, state FROM items WHERE user = :user");
        $itemQuery->execute(['user'=>$_SESSION['user_id']]);
        $items = $itemQuery->rowCount() ? $itemQuery : [];
    ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Todo</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container_fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <h1 class="col-md-12 text-center">Todo</h1>
        </div>  
        <div class="row list_container">
            <div class="todo_column col-md-4">                      
                <ul>
                    <?php foreach($items as $item): ?>  
                        <?php if($item['state'] == 1): ?>   
                            <li>
                                <span><?php echo $item['name']; ?></span><br /> 
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">-></button>       
                            </li>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>        
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="working_column col-md-4">
                <ul>
                    <?php foreach($items as $item): ?>  
                        <?php if($item['state'] == 2): ?>   
                            <li>
                                <span><?php echo $item['name']; ?></span><br /> 
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">-></button>       
                            </li>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>        
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="finished_column col-md-4">
                <ul>
                    <?php foreach($items as $item): ?>  
                        <?php if($item['state'] == 3): ?>   
                            <li>
                                <span><?php echo $item['name']; ?></span><br /> 
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">-></button>       
                            </li>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>        
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div><!-- end of list_container-->


        <div class="row">
            <form action="add.php" method="post" class="col-md-12 item_add">
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Write your task" class="input col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" required>
                <button type="submit" value="add" class="btn btn-success col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">Add Task</button>


            </form>
        </div>

    </div> <!-- end of container -->    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what your specific question is?

Comment: It seems that my foreach loops after my first one are not repeating through the array, or are showing my database array as empty. How can I make the foreach loops after my first one go back over the same array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed that you are using PDO. Try this:

```
require_once 'app/init.php';
$query = "SELECT id, name, state FROM items WHERE user = :user";
$itemQuery = $db->prepare($query);
$itemQuery->execute(['user'=>$_SESSION['user_id']]);
$items = $itemQuery->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: I pulled my code and added yours in. I got a bunch of errors like this -> Warning: Illegal string offset 'state' in C:\Users\you\Desktop\WebDev\stack\wamp64\www\todov2\index.php on line 30.

Comment: I edited code, `fetchAll` would be better in your case

Comment: Edited again, should be sufficient